# Jboss Admin Console - blocked by .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, admin, jboss7.x

I installed a clean jboss 7.1.Final Server.

after running it, I made an sh add_user.sh in the bin folder

I chose a) for Management User

I entered:
Realm (ManagementRealm) : joerg
Username : joerg
Password : superpassword
Re-enter Password : superpassword

when I entered then http://localhost:9990/console/  it was forwarded to http://localhost:9990/console/App.html

the problem is, that if I go to the URL http://localhost:9990/console/App.html I can't log in, because i get the typical HTTP-Basic Authentication promt for username and password (looks like there is a .htaccess but i never made one)

If I try
login: joerg
password: superpassword
it is not working

(on the shell the username and password works with the jboss diagnostic reporter jdr.sh)

Comment: okay, i got the solution...  
stupid me.  

i MUST leave the realm field blank!

problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you will need to enter the ManagementRealm as the realm that your primary user account will resolve to. Your example would be:

```
Realm (ManagementRealm) : ManagementRealm
Username : joerg
Password : superpassword
Re-enter Password : superpassword
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-ManagingyourJBossApplicationServer7), this is explained as follows:

> It is important to leave the name of the realm as 'ManagementRealm' as
>   this needs to match the name used in the server's configuration, for
>   the remaining fields enter the new username, password and password
>   confirmation.
>
> Provided there are no errors in the values entered you will then be
>   asked to confirm that you want to add the user, the user will be
>   written to the properties files used for authentication and a
>   confirmation message will be displayed.

With [JBoss Application Server 7.1.x](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads) being so customisable, you can build your own realm configurations as required, but for the initial instance, make sure you use the ManagementRealm.

Comment: thx for your answer.
I wanted to answer the question by myself, but I had to wait for 8 hours, so i answered it in the comments under the question. (but with this i couldn't flag it, as answered!)

Comment: I remember the Stack Overflow FAQ's recommended answering own questions, and I love that you came back to do that. Certainly helps other people in the future, and especially on fresh releases like AS7.1.x. You're an early adopter ;)

Comment: it was the newest stable release on the download page ;)

Answer (score 1):

Folow these steps:

```
open jboss-as-x.x.x.Final\standalone\configuration\mgmt-users.properties and delete the user (i.e delete the line which has the username you want to use, such as admin=2c7123264278731425d1f53aeb55da1e)
open jboss-as-x.x.x.Final\domain\configuration\mgmt-users.properties and delete the user (i.e delete the line which has the username you want to use, such as admin=2c7123264278731425d1f53aeb55da1e)
```

run jboss-as-x.x.x.Final\bin\add-user.bat and add user in the following way:

1. Select user type a
2. Realm (ManagementRealm) : ManagementRealm
3. Username : admin
4. Password : password
5. Re-enter Password : password

If you get JBAS015243: The user ‘admin’ already exists in at least one properties file. error, then you didn't complete steps 1 and 2.